# Unified NSToolBar/Titlebar with icons and labels?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

Our designer wants a unified toolbar/titlebar (such as what Safari, XCode, et. al use) but wants labels under the icons. I have the display mode on my NSToolbar set to `IconAndLabel` but I still only get icons... if I do separate title and toolbars the labels show up.

I've found nothing in the docu or even via googling that suggests you're forced into icon-only view but that seems to be the case. What's the best way to get labels on these buttons? I want to avoid putting the labels in my image assets as that will complicate localization, so if that's the only choice I'd have to do it programmatically using a localized string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of having both the new unified toolbar and labels. Maybe you could put a bar under the toolbar that contains the labels, aligned perfectly to the images.

**But** do you really need the labels? Apple is trying get rid of them with the new toolbar design. Try to make your icons as self-explanatory as possible. Don't forget that there are tool tips available as well for the button titles..